# Problem : The <p> tag is not displayed on my <div>

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm setting up a website myself, but today something is driving me mad..
The `<p>` tag for text ( yes, yes) isn't displayed in a div. Here's my website: MorphrDB.cf

I'm using a CSS grid, for the header section the `<p>` tag seems to work but on the 'middle' class (this is a column) it doesn't work.
I tried to modify CSS, overflow, hidden text, inherit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content ="
    21i2l90JHpCEpQXxaLRvDhtyxGrlSCWc6T__wh1ySN0" />
    <!-- Device compatibility-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Scripts & Languages-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Styles (Css) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-generic"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylize.css">
    <!-- Begin -->
    <title>MorphR_Db</title>
  </head>
  <body id="Back">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="header" id="header-back">
          <p class="title">MorphR DataBase</p>
          <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='morphrdb.cf/index.html'>Home</a></li>
              <li class='active'><a href='#'>Links</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Help</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Forum/">Forum</a></li>
                  <li><a href='/Help/'>Help Page</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='#'>Files</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href='/Repositories/'>Repositories</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Files/">Files</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='/SeA/'>Suggest or Add</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href='/About/'>About</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Contact/'>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
       /* here*/ <div class="middle">
          <p>sample text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the p tag should be displayed (sorry the css is missing) but not ( here yes, but in my website no :c)

Comment: To figure out what's going on, use the browser "Inspector" tool to find the element in the DOM and see what its CSS rules are.

Comment: Can you please add the css or create a jsfiddle? We can't really help you if we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: And `/*...*/` aren't HTML comment marks... Use `<!-- ... -->`

Comment: yes i just added that thinked out it'll be css --" but thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: but i thinki solved it : i added a selector id in the p tag and then added in the css color: #f1f1f1; and now it's working! Also what is Jsfiddle?

Comment: Please include the CSS too so we can replicate the issue, difficult to say just seing the HTML.

Comment: ok i'll add it.

Comment: https://www.morphrdb.cf/css/grid.css there you go and thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your CSS code it states:

```
/* Style the middle column */
.middle {
  grid-area: middle;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Since this means *black* background-color and, the text not showing, also is black (and is within the `.middle` element) - that's a problem. Either change the text color, or the background-color.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe hide because text and background color similarity.
try like below..

```
<p style="color: black">text..</p>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135977/6080831), and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.